# Ubuntu 22.04 laptop sudden shutdown after full charge

Tags: 22.04, power-management, shutdown, laptop, battery

So I recently removed windows 11 and installed ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop (lenovo ideapad flex 5 with amd ryzen 7) after i had sudden shutdown issues even though battery was full at times. Now this issue has started here as well and it's happening more often than it happened before. I charge it to 99% after which the % won't increase to a 100 and after switching the charger off and using it for some time, it suddenly shuts down and won't start. Later, I have to plug in a charger and start it, and it keeps showing 0% and the orange battery icon shows even though it's plugged in and keeps being stuck at 0%. Later after hours and hours it suddenly becomes ok. I gave it to my local lenovo service center but they said they couldn't find any issues. What should I do? Should I change the battery and/or the motherboard? The laptop is still under warranty.

Comment: It’s a hardware problem - maybe battery, maybe motherboard, maybe charger; most likely battery. It’s happened in 2 operating systems - I would definitely seek a replacement / repair if under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be a problem with the battery.
But I would suggest that you take your laptop to the repair shop.

EDIT: It also could be the problem with CMOS battery/cell.